# excel-2007 record macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, excel-2003

I just wanted to know why Excel-2007 record macro does not write anything for example when I do the following:

I insert a rectangle on the sheet and change its backcolor...

(On the other hand, if I do the same thing in Excel-2003 I get some code.)

Also, is it possible to use VB to ask Excel to put the rectangle on specified position; for example my current active cell is A10:C10

I want my rectangle's upper left corner to be on that location, i.e. A10:C10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about your first question, but as for your second, use the cell Left and Top properties as the Left and Top for the rectangle. This is VBA:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ActiveSheet

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = shtCells(3, 4)
sht.Shapes.AddShape msoShapeRectangle, rng.Left, rng.Top, 30, 40
```